# What does $0 < x_1 < x_2 < 1$ really mean when $y_1 = x_1/x_2$ and $y_2 = x_2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am really having trouble seeing why

$$0 < x_1 < x_2 < 1$$
is equaivalent to

$$0 < y_1 < 1, \space 0<y_2<1$$

when 
$$y_1 = x_1/x_2, \space y_2 = x_2$$.

The part that I am having trouble seeing is that

$$0 < y_1y_2 < y_2 < 1$$ is equivalent to

$$0 < y_2 <1$$

I really want to say

$$0 < y_1 < 1 < \frac{1}{y_2}$$

therefore

$$\infty > \frac{1}{y_1} > 1 > y_2$$

Therefore $y_2 < \frac{1}{y_1}$.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: The above is valid in the same way that $0<1<2<3$ implies $0<2<3$

Comment: That does make sense. Why is it that people see this?   don't know . . .

Comment: Don't worry if you can't see this immediately. Some can, and the others learn to do so by doing many such problems like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $0<x_2<1$ and $y_2=x_2$ we get $0<y_2<1.$

Since $x_1>0$ and $x_2>0$ we have that $\frac{x_1}{x_2}>0.$ From $x_1<x_2$ we derive $\frac{x_1}{x_2}<1.$

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  Finally, something that I understand.  One quick question if you do not mind, though.  Would my last expression in the question be invalid?